# I keep getting "Wrong Number of Arguments (given 1, expected 0)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working through a class via StackSkills and their question links are gone.

I am setting up a business program. So far I have the database set up to store invoice information (date, tax rate, sales person, company name). I followed the instructions to create a search field in the invoice list that would allow me to search by date range. When I try to load the invoice list, I get an error saying:

```
ArgumentError in InvoicesController#index
wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
Extracted source (around line #7):              
5  # GET /invoices.json
6  def index
7    @search = InvoiceSearch.new(params[:search])
8    @invoices = @search.scope
9  end
```

This is the code that was added to my InvoicesController.rb file for this exercise:

```
def index
    @search = InvoiceSearch.new(params[:search])
    @invoices = @search.scope
end
```

This is the invoice_Search.rb that was created in this lesson:

```
class InvoiceSearch
    attr_reader :date_from, :date_to

    def initializ(params)
        params ||={}
        @date_from = parsed_date(params[:date_from], 7.days.ago.to_date.to_s)
        @date_to = parsed_date(params[:date_to], Date.today.to_s)
    end

    def scope
        Invoice.where('date BETWEEN ? AND ?', @date_from, @date_to)
    end

    private

    def parsed_date(date_string, default)
        Date.parse(date_string)

    rescue ArgumentError, TypeError
        default
    end

end
```

And this is what was added to my index.html.erb file for this lesson (the page that lists the invoices in the database):

```
<div class="row">
  <h1>Listing Invoices</h1>
  <div class="pull-right range-query">
    <%= form_tag invoices_path, method: :get do %>
      <%= text_field_tag 'search[date_from]', @search.date_from %>
      <%= text_field_tag 'search[date_to]', @search.date_to %>
      <%= submit_tag 'Search', class: 'btn search-button' %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 8):

Change

```
initializ
```

to:

```
initialize
```

Comment: exactly! (: eagle eye

Comment: Yep, that was it.  Such a silly spelling mistake.  I don't know how many times I looked at that too.  Thank you!!